# Adding a dictionary to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

So I way trying to make a simple password manager using python and I got a problem. I cannot add a dictionary to a DataFrame. It gives me - "Empty DataFrame"

```
import pandas as pd

start = int(input('Welcome to the password manager! Type in pass:'))
password = 12345
while True:
    if start == password:
        table = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Service', 'Login', 'Password'],)
        service = input('Service name:')
        login = input('Login:')
        passw = input('Password:')
        row = {'Service': service, 'Login': login, 'Password': passw}
        table.append(row, ignore_index=True)
        print(table.head(3))
        break
    else:
        print('Access denied')
        break
```

Comment: Please explain why you use `while` loop, whilst both `if` body and `else` body have `break`, i.e. there will always be single run

Comment: Should not I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is not need for the while loop while using break it have no sense.

Secondly, for your code you forgot to assign the value to the result

```
table = table.append(row, ignore_index=True)
```